# How to Add a Legend to a ggplot without plotting the raw data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made a plot of a polynomial function: y = x^2 - 6*x + 9

with a series of several points in a sequence + minor standard error in y. I used these points to construct a spline model for that function from the raw data points, and then I calculated the derivative from the spline model with R's predict() function and then I added both of the spline curves to the plot.

By the way, the expected derivative function is this: dy / dx = 2*x - 6

The original function I colored blue and the 1st derivative function I colored red. I wish to add legends to these plots, but I'm finding that difficult since I did not assign any points to the plots, as I declared the data-frames within the geom_smooth() functions.

The code I'm using is this:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Plot the function: f(x) = x^2 - 6x + 9
# with a smooth spline:
# And then the deriviative of that function from predicted values of the 
# smoothed spline: f ' (x) = 2*x - 6

# Get a large sequence of x-values:
x <- seq(from = -10, to = 10, by = 0.01)

# The y-values are a function of each x value. 
y <- x^2 - 6*x + 9 + rnorm(length(x), 0, 0.5)

# Fit the curve to a model which is a smoothed spine. 
model <- smooth.spline(x = x, y = y)

# Predict the 1st derivative of this smoothed spline.
f_x <- predict(model, x = seq(from = min(x), to = max(x), by = 1), deriv = 1)

# Plot the smoothed spline of the original function and the derivative with respect to x.
p <- ggplot() + theme_bw() + geom_smooth(data = data.frame(x,y), aes(x = x, y = y), method = "loess", col = "blue", se = TRUE) + geom_smooth(data = data.frame(f_x$x, f_x$y), aes(x = f_x$x, y = f_x$y), method = "loess", col = "red", se = TRUE)

# Set the bounds of the plot.
p <- p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 20), limits = c(-5, 10)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 20), limits = c(-10, 10))

# Add some axis labels 
p <- p + labs(x = "x-axis", y = "y-axis", title = "Original Function and predicted derivative function")

p <- p + scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red"), labels = c("Original Function", "Derivative Function with respect to x"))

print(p)
```

I was hoping that I could add the legend with scale_fill_manual(), but my attempt does not add a legend to the plot. Essentially, the plot I get generally looks like this, minus the messy legend that I added in paint. I would like that legend, thank you.

[image]

I did this because I want to show to my chemistry instructor that I can accurately measure the heat capacity just from the points from differential scanning calorimetry data for which I believe the heat capacity is just the first derivative plot of heat flow vs Temperature differentiated with respect to temperature.

So I tried to make a plot showing the original function overlayed with the 1st derivative function with respect to x, showing that the plot of the first derivative made only from a spline curve fitted to raw data points reliably produces the expected line dy / dx = 2 * x - 6, which it does.

I just want to add that legend.

Comment: Put the `color` options for the smoothers within the `aes`, then use `p <- p + scale_color_manual(name = "Functions", values = c("blue", "red"), labels = c("Original Function", "Derivative Function with respect to x"))` instead of your last row of code, et voilá.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a data frame with you data and use color within aesthetics is the most common way of doing this.

```
df <- rbind(
  data.frame(data='f(x)', x=x, y=y),
  data.frame(data='f`(x)', x=f_x$x, y=f_x$y))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y, color=data)) + geom_smooth(method = 'loess')
p <- p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 20), limits = c(-5, 10)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 20), limits = c(-10, 10))
p <- p + labs(x = "x-axis", y = "y-axis", title = "Original Function and predicted derivative function")
p <- p + scale_color_manual(name = "Functions", values = c("blue", "red"), labels = c("Original Function", "Derivative Function with respect to x"))
print(p)
```

Comment: I've changed it to `scale_color_manual`, won't work with `fill` as the `fill` option is not used in OPs code. I also added a name to the legend :) Also, you will need to specify `method = "loess"` for the smoother, else it'll try to use `gam` and fail.

Comment: Thank you. This is easy to understand.